# Recoding data.fame object from latin1 to utf-8

Tags: r, utf-8, character-encoding, latin1, googlevis

I work with windows 7 (my system: "LC_COLLATE=French_France.1252) with data with accents.
My data are coded in ANSI which allows me to visualize them correctly in the tabs of Rstudio.

My problem: When I want to a create GoogleVis page (encoding utf-8), the accented characters are not displayed correctly.

What I expected: I am looking to convert my latin1 Data.frames in utf-8 with R just before creating googleVis pages.
 I have no ideas. Stringi package seems only to work with raw data.

```
fr <- data.frame(âge = c(15,20), prénom = c("Adélia", "Adão"), row.names = c("I1", "I2"))

print (fr)

library (googleVis)

test <- gvisTable(fr)
plot(fr)
```

the real data
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B91cr4hfMXV4OEkzWk1aWlhvR0E
[image]

```
# importing (historical data)
test_ansi<-read.table("databig_ansi.csv",
                header=TRUE, sep=",",
                na.strings="",
                quote = "\"",
                dec=".") 

# subsetting 
library (dplyr)
test_ansi <- 
   test_ansi %>%
   count(ownera)

# library (stringi)

  stri_enc_detect(test_ansi$ownera)

# visualisation
library (googleVis)

testvis <- gvisTable(test_ansi)
plot(testvis)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are built-in functions in several packages, such as `stringi`, `stringr`, `SoundexBR`, `tau`, as well as a character convert in the R base system, which can be used as:

`text2 <- iconv(text, from = "latin1", to = "UTF-8")`

You may also want a more specific function with some checks for factors, like the following:

```
.fromto <- function (x, from, to)
{
    if (is.list(x)) {
    xattr <- attributes(x)
    x <- lapply(x, .fromto, from, to)
    attributes(x) <- xattr
    } else {
    if (is.factor(x)) {
        levels(x) <- iconv(levels(x), from, to, sub = "byte")
    } else {
        if (is.character(x))
        x <- iconv(x, from, to, sub = "byte")
    }
    lb <- attr(x, "label")
    if (length(lb) > 0) {
        attr(x, "label") <- iconv(attr(x, "label"), from, to, sub = "byte")
    }
    }
    x
}

# This will convert a vector from any encoding into UTF-8
Latin2UTF8 <- function (x, from = "WINDOWS-1252")
{
    .fromto(x, from, "UTF-8")
}
```

Then you just use it as:

```
Latin2UTF8(fr)
 âge prénom
I1  15 Adélia
I2  20   Adão
```

**Extra edits after extra information and data**

This is how my R is setup. My R is running on UTF-8 locale and English by default. Once my system environment differs from the file encoding provided, I'll use `fileEncoding = "LATIN1"`. That is all.

```
> Sys.getlocale()
[1] "en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8"


test_ansi<-read.table(file.choose(),
                       header=TRUE, sep=",",
                       na.strings="",
                        quote = "\"",
                        dec=".", fileEncoding = "LATIN1")

> test_ansi2 <- 
+     test_ansi %>%
+     count(ownera)
> test_ansi2
Source: local data frame [6,482 x 2]

                ownera n
1       Abautret (Vve) 1
2              Abazuza 1
3            Abernathy 1
4  Abrahamsen, Heerman 1
5  Abrahamsen, Hereman 6
6   Abrahamsz, Heerman 2
7         Abram, Ralph 8
8      Abrams, Heerman 2
9            Abranches 1
10               Abreu 1
..                 ... .

# visualisation
library (googleVis)


testvis <- gvisTable(test_ansi)
plot(testvis)
```

[Link to the table created](http://127.0.0.1:10000/custom/googleVis/TableID2251c0b8aaf.html)

[image: Table]

Comment: @Wilcar What exactly is not working? What is the error message? It works fine for me, may be you can read the data already in the desired format or change the locale encoding of your system for while. I'll add extra stuff in my answer.

Comment: here are 3 screen captures:  RStdudio provides good visualization of ansi data  but not in GoogleVis (look at names with accents).  Maybe I do not know use your function?

[![import ansi][1]][1]
[![Rstudio][2]][2]
[![GoogleVis][3]][3]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/F5JHI.jpg
  [2]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/JVHSE.jpg
  [3]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/gYr16.jpg

Comment: I post 3 screen captures. in my last comment. Maybe I don't corectly use your function: when a recode my d.f. the data vizualisation is still good in RStudio. (system windows 1252)

Comment: It would be very awkward, but maybe the problem you have is not the way R reads and stores the strings, but what sys locale GoogleVis is inheriting from it.

Comment: Notice that in my last edit I didn't even use the function I proposed. Once I'm running on UTF-8 encoding, I just loaded the data with its proper encoding.  If you use library(string); stri_enc_detect(test_ansi); stri_enc_isutf8(test_ansi); what do you get? You may have a bounce of encoding, which may be causing some confusion for GoogleVis.

Comment: Unfortunately I can not test today ... I will test this evening (local time in Paris). A strange thing: if your function is good, my data would not be displayed properly in RStudio ....

Comment: I just remind you that the data encoded in UTF 8 does not display correctly in the tabs of R Studio (windows 1252) but correctly in an HTML page (GoogleVis). Are encoding options  character of Rstudo important? They have no effects in my case.

Comment: R or RStudio encoding is not relevant if what you want in the GoogleVis table encoded right. It's really beyond the question here, but maybe there is a little confusion which encoding to use in the process of transversing data between R and GoogleVis server. I guess it's because your data may be encoded with multiple encoding styles, it would be really awkward, but may happen.

Comment: I completed my question with  stri_enc_detect (x$names) results.  the results are both similar before and after the use of your function.