# Incorrect display due to encode probem with googleVis function

Tags: r, encode, googlevis

I'am trying to use the googleViz package to plot a Sankey Diagram. But The encode is not right and the output doesn't display the right encode. I coulnd't find a solution. I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34496328/recoding-data-fame-object-from-latin1-to-utf-8), but it didn't help me (or I didn't understand the accepted answer).

Here's a minimum reproducible example, using another function from googleVis package.

fr <- data.frame(âge = c(15,20), prénom = c("Adélia", "Adão"), row.names = c("I1", "I2"))

library (googleVis)

test <- gvisTable(fr)
plot(test)

[image: result in my pc]

Can anyone help me? Here's my session info.
R version 3.5.0 (2018-04-23)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)
locale:
[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34496328/recoding-data-fame-object-from-latin1-to-utf-8) LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252

googleVis_0.6.3